# CSS div overflow with absolutely positioned elements

Tags: css, html, resize, overflow

I have an absolutely positioned layout with three main divs: the header, the left options column, and the content column. The designed behavior is to have the header and left option column stay on the page at all times, while the content column is able to freely scroll up and down (picture a control panel to the left and title bar at the top).

The problem is window resizing and left-right (x-axis) overflow within the content div. My desired behavior is to have a minimum width of about 1000 pixels, at which point a horizontal scrollbar shows up within the content column and allows the user to scroll over. This prevents the window from being resized so small to the point where my layout no longer looks as intended.

I had attempted to use the min-width directive within my existing CSS, but to no avail. min-width DOES achieve the "cutoff" I'm looking for, however, no horizontal scrollbar turns up and I am unable to scroll horizontally.

Is there a way to do this using the existing paradigm, or does the style sheet need to be done differently? The following is my existing implementation (with the min-width attribute I have been testing for content_column):

```
html {
    overflow: hidden; 
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 0px none;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #146647;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}

#option_column {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #0F4C35;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 155px;
    padding: 3px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content_column {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40px;
    left: 161px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And this is my HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        Head
    </div>

    <div id="option_column">
        Option Column
    </div>

    <div id="content_column">
        <div class="header_text">Content Header</div>
        <div id="subheader">
            Content (content_column intended to stop resizing at 1000px)
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Starting point fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4M43d/

Comment: "I have an absolutely positioned layout (...) does the style sheet need to be done differently". I'd be tempted to answer YES.

Comment: Yeah, it's rare that deliberate horizontal scrolling is a good idea. It's a hassle for your user. Also, your 1000px content column plus a sidebar means that the majority of your visitors will not be able to see the full width of your site. Unless you have some strange requirement, I'd rethink this plan.

Answer (score 1):

On the contents section set

`width:1000px;`

`overflow-y: auto;`

But this way the width will always stay at 1000px.
In other words, as follows

```
#content_column {
position: absolute;
width: 1000px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x:scroll; /* override overflow:hidden; applied to body & html */
z-index: 1;
top: 40px;
left: 161px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 3px;
background: #E5E5E5;
color: #000000;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Doing this still does not permit me to horizontally scroll (it just "cuts off").

Comment: Try `width: 1000px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:scroll;`. Also, try removing `overflow:hidden;` in the body and html tags and apply `overflow` property only to the contents section.

Comment: I updated the code above to take into account `overflow-x:scroll;`.

Comment: Also, for the horizontal scrollbar to work the contents of the `div#content_column` must have width set. For, example in the contents area you could write `<!-- the following will scroll --><div style="width:1200px;">My main contents.</div>`.

Comment: Removing "overflow: hidden" from my html element causes the entire page to scroll left/right, breaking the overlay illusion intended by the header and left column (the header and column as a page will move left instead of just the content div).

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
#content_column {overflow-x: scroll}
```

do? Note that IE < 9 doesn't do axis-specific overflow, so you'd have to use `{overflow: scroll}`.

Comment: "overflow-x: scroll" places a disabled horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the div. After resizing the window past the point where I should be able to horizontally scroll, it stays disabled and doesn't work.

Comment: Also, noticed that resizing the window will also cause the window to "overlap" the scrollbar (i.e. once i hit the min-width, instead of the scrollbar activating, the window just resizes over it.)